# Dúvidas com regras da PlayStore

Tags: google-play

Recentemente (05.05.2018) meu aplicativo foi suspenso da playstore.
Isso foi oque eu recebi pelo email.

> Hi Developers at Wallace Robertoc,
>
> After review, Áudio Memes, com.robertoc.audiomemes, has been suspended and removed from Google Play as a policy strike because it violates the sexually explicit content policy.
>
> Next Steps
>
> Read through the [Sexually Explicit](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox/16334c0cf6009088) Content policy for more details and examples of policy violations.
>   Make sure your app complies with all policies listed in the [Developer Program Policies](https://play.google.com/intl/pt-BR/about/developer-content-policy/#!?modal_active=none). Remember additional enforcement could occur if there are further policy issues with your apps.
>   If it’s possible to bring your app into compliance, you can sign in to your Play Console and submit the policy compliant app using a new package name and a new app name.
>   Additional suspensions of any nature may result in the termination of your developer account, and investigation and possible termination of related Google accounts. If your account is terminated, payments will cease and Google may recover the proceeds of any past sales and/or the cost of any associated fees (such as chargebacks and transaction fees) from you.
>
> If you’ve reviewed the policy and feel this suspension may have been in error, please reach out to our [policy support team](http://privado). One of my colleagues will get back to you within 2 business days.
>
> Regards,
>
> The Google Play Review Team

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como podem ver o motivo da suspensão foi o famoso gemidão,
só que existe inúmeros casos que o mesmo aparece na PlayStore 
em forma de conteúdo ou até mesmo em nomes de aplicativos.
Porque o meu foi escolhido?

Provávelmente foi uma denúncia de um usuário, já que tem um ícone do
NetFlix lá em cima, enfim.

> Meu aplicativo pode conter palavrões (Escrita)?
>
> Meu aplicativo pode conter palavrões (Áudio)?

Estou ciente que foi conteúdo sexualmente explícito.

No começo do app não havia tantos palavrões e nem o gemidão, então na classificação do app eu respondi o questionário mais levemente, então será que se eu re-upar o app e colocar ele o mais adulto possível essas coisas poderão passar no crivo da GooglPlay?

Comment: *Porque o meu foi escolhido?* Provavelmente alguém denunciou. *Meu aplicativo pode conter palavrões?* A [Central de políticas do desenvolvedor](https://play.google.com/intl/pt-BR/about/developer-content-policy/index.html) não cita se pode ou não. Você pode entrar em contato com o suporte da Google para verificar a possibilidade de reativar o app.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta @Valdeir. Vou esperar mais respostas antes de agir.

Answer (score 0):

De acordo com **[Central de Políticas do Desenvolvedor da Google](https://play.google.com/intl/pt-BR_ALL/about/restricted-content/inappropriate-content/sexually-explicit-content/)**

> Conteúdo sexualmente explícito
>   Não são permitidos apps que tenham ou promovam conteúdo sexual explícito, como pornografia. Em geral, não são permitidos conteúdos ou serviços com o objetivo de satisfação sexual.
>
> **Veja alguns exemplos de violações comuns:**
>
> - Representações de atos sexuais ou poses sexualmente sugestivas.
> - Imagens promocionais de brinquedos sexuais.
> - Conteúdo que retrate,
>     descreva ou encoraje a bestialidade.
> - Apps que promovam serviços de
>     acompanhantes ou outros serviços que possam ser interpretados como
>     fornecimento de atos sexuais em troca de uma compensação.

O som do gemido pode entrar nessa categoria por isso deverá remover esse tipo de conteúdo ou em diálogo com o Suporte da Google da Google chegar a um consenso que permita esse tipo de contéudo.

Também pode pedir um auxílio para a solução do problema.